# Query Cloud firestore based on price

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a recyclerciew that I display according to the criteria that the user has to enter. Ex for text, I proceed like this:

```
query = db.collection("RESTO_TABLE")
    .whereEqualTo("state", s.toString())
    .orderBy("state", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
FirestoreRecyclerOptions < RestoModel > Options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder < RestoModel > ()
    .setQuery(query, RestoModel.class)
    .build();
villeAdapter.updateOptions(Options);
```

I would then like to make a display according to the entry price. I did this but it seems not to be correct.

```
query = db.collection("RESTO_TABLE")
    .whereEqualTo("price", s.toString())
    .orderBy("price", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
FirestoreRecyclerOptions < RestoModel > Options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder < RestoModel > ()
    .setQuery(query, RestoModel.class)
    .build();
visiteurRestoAdapter.updateOptions(Options);
```

Like if user write 1500, recyclerview should display all item getting price < = 1500 .
Any idea? Thank you ..

Answer (score 2):

If the price field is a numeric, then providing a string to the query won't work the way you expect.  This is trying to filter price by some string value:

```
.whereEqualTo("price",s.toString())
```

Perhaps you meant to [convert string to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813533/converting-string-to-number-in-java) first before querying.

Comment: I got the result with the integer conversion. In addition, my searches are not dynamic. At the current state, the user must enter exactly the existing value in the database before firestore can return the item entered while in the normal order of things, results must be offered to the user as soon as the first letter corresponding to the entry in the database. Moreover, when the user enters in upper case while in the database, the result is in lower case, the result is not found. I know I should make a change in my condition

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
query = db.collection("RESTO_TABLE")
          .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("price", 1500)
          .orderBy("price",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [query operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators).