# how to get the numeric value (integer or float) of a string?

Tags: java

Hi everyone I am trying to get the numeric value inside a string. So far this method works well for me to obtain integers. But now I would also like to be able to obtain numbers that contain decimals.

if I want to extract the number that a String contains I use:
getNumbers("delay: 5 days")
output = 5

Now I want to get the number of "this a sample, delay: 7.1 days"
output = 7.1
Remark: the str always can change, but always will have a number (integer or float)

```
public String getNumbers(String str){
        str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", " ");
        str = str.trim();
    
        str = str.replaceAll(" +", " ");
        
        if (str.equals(""))
           return "-1";
    
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: does `Double#parseDouble(String)` accomplish your needs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting String to Number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813533/converting-string-to-number-in-java)

Comment: Your `replaceAll`, `trim` and `replaceAll` seems a little cumbersome...

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the link given, since the primary programming problem in this question is isolating the characters that make up the number.  But hey, anything will do for the close-at-all-costs crew.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for retrieving only digits from string, try this:

```
String numbers = Double.valueOf(yourStrValue.replaceAll("[^\\d.]+|\\.(?!\\d)", "")).toString()
```

but watch out for discrete numbers will be merged by this way. For example if u have `34fdf^.98` this process produced `34.98`

Comment: Just use the R.E. to extract the number rather than replacing the characters that are not the number 
        `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").match(str); if (m.find()) return Double.valueOf(m.group(0));`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Double.parseDouble(str)` in order to parse the double value. However, keep in mind that you will need to remove all the non-number characters from the string.